# SQLITE - IDbConnection c# .net last_insert_rowid

Tags: c#, sqlite

i have an issue by getting last_insert_rowid in my sqlite db in c#. Here is what i have, the insert with my dynamic params works well for my project and i like to keep this methode constant:

```
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
{
int erg = cnn.Execute("insert into tblPerson (Vorname, Nachname, Ort) values(@Vorname, @Nachname, @Ort);", tblPerson);
}
```

That works fine, but this method don't allow me to access the last inserted id. But i need this: `cnn.last_insert_rowid()`.
IDbConnection have no definition for last_insert_rowid or something like that. And a select last_insert_rowid( ), give an error: "no definition for cnn.last_insert_rowid()"

Do someone have a idea, please no workarounds like `select * from tblPerson ORDER BY tblPerson DESC`
I realy need the confirmed last inserted id (idPerson).
idPerson is my Primary-Key and is Autoincrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `select last_insert_rowid();` to the end of the sql string, and update the calling code to use `Query()` instead of `Execute()` so you can check the result of the additional select statement.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for your response <3
i use dynamic paramenters to insert, so i like to stay with that method. so i cannot change Execute to Query.

Comment: nvm. u right, Query works, and i added the select last_insert_rowid();. omg, thank u so much!